# if else condition 'else' is not working

Tags: php, mysqli

**/MY CODE/**

The if part is working properly but else is not working.
i even tried $variable instead of direct echo but still it is not working 'else'

**Updated**

```
    <?php
   $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root' ,'', 'timeline');

    if(!$db) {

        echo 'Could not connect to the database.';
    } else {

        if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
            $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);

            if(strlen($queryString) >0) {

                $query = $db->query("SELECT collegename FROM college WHERE collegename LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");
                if(isset($query)) {
                echo '<ul>';
                    while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                        echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($result->collegename).'\');">'.$result->collegename.'</li>';
                    }
                echo '</ul>';

                } else {

                    echo 'create some'; // this part is not working


                }
            } else {
                // do nothing
            }
        } else {
            echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
        }
    }
?>
```

help me out.....
 even read lots of like problem on stackoverflow but no real return

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: You should really say exactly WHAT is actually not working. Your else block is rather huge.

Comment: @Charminbear written there which else part is not working -- // ` echo 'create some'; ` // this part is not working

Comment: First echo $queryString  and see data is coming or not

Comment: First echo $queryString  and see data is coming or not

Comment: @siddhesh if condition is working properly but only else is not working there..

Comment: The if conditions works then never else condition will be exectued that's why it's called as if... else...

Comment: @siddhesh  mean to say when query executes itself as the above condition [ IF CONDITION ] then it works but in "else condition" WHEN condition NOT matched --- the else is not working

Comment: have you tried the dumping of variable $query  using var_dump() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) then your `if(isset($query))` statement will always be evaluated as true, as `$query` would be either `FALSE` or a [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object. `isset` returns `TRUE` for both these values, so your `else` code will never be called.

Documentation on [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

> Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL, FALSE otherwise.

Use `if($query !== false)` instead.

*Update*

It also seems like you are checking `$query` to see whether or not there was a hit in the database. You need to check the [number of rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) in the result for that, e.g:

```
if ($query !== false && $query->num_rows > 0) {
   // Query was ok and at least one row was returned
}
else {
   // Will be reached if query was bad or there were no hits
}
```

Comment: i even removed isset and tried my code, but same result is coming --i.e else not working

Comment: See my update. You seem to be confusing the result of the query with number of hits.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    if($query_run = $db->query("SELECT collegename FROM college WHERE collegename LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10")){

    echo '<ul>';
                  while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                            echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($result->collegename).'\');">'.$result->collegename.'</li>';
                  }

 echo '</ul>';
    } else {
         echo 'create some';
    }
```

Comment: How are you checking whether your else is working or not